# Retrieve URL Parameters

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm creating an app where each list will have multiple tasks.

The URL for creating a new task would be like `/lists/:listId/tasks`

In my `app.js` I'm doing this to redirect that URL to a specific route file called `tasks.js`:

```
app.use('/lists/:listId/tasks', tasks);
```

Then in my `tasks.js` I'm doing the following:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.listId) //This doesn't work.
});
```

**How can I get the params from the `tasks.js`?.** Also, if there is a better way to implement what I want, I would be more than happy to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/696

If you put your params route to `tasks.js` file then the problem will be solved automatically. Like:

In `app.js`

```
app.use('/lists', tasks);
```

In `tasks.js`

```
router.post('/:listId/tasks', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.listId);
});
```

It will work properly.

Comment: Isn't there a way to pass the params as well?.

Comment: I don't think so, but given link of this issue in my answer i think express.js did not support this type of route

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've adopted for this scenario is the following:

```js
app.use('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res, next) => {
    res.local.params = req.params;  //in res.local you can store whatever you want
    next();
}, tasks);
```

Then you can access res.local from `tasks.js` routes.

Answer (score -1):

i think this should work

```
app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.listId);
})
```

To redirect! Try this

```
app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.listId);
  //if you have a route set up already 
  res.redirect('/task');
})
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the parameters in the route, not in the same call!.